# Grouping list indices by value

Tags: python

Given something like:

```
l = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3]
```

I want:

```
[[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8,9], [10,11]]
```

Right now, I am doing:

```
[[elem[0] for elem in list(g)] for k, g in itertools.groupby(
enumerate(l), lambda x: x[1])]
```

Is there a better and faster and simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: why did I get a -1 for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty simple.

```
result = []
last = None
for i, this in enumerate(a):
    if this != last:
        sub = []
        result.append(sub)
        last = this
    sub.append(i)
```

Comment: na it's good effort nonetheless I am running speed test on it, who knows ;)

Comment: @Jack - how did the timing test turn out?

Comment: Your function comes out about twice faster. Good one :)

--- 1.7479839325 seconds ---
--- 3.26843309402 seconds ---

The problem is probably where I loop within the list again